# Geolocation coordinates are not ready by geolib in a react-native state

Tags: react-native, npm, geolocation

I am using geolib on react-native and integrating it with geolocation. I want to get the distance from my current location lat/long to another location's lat/long. When I do that, it pops out the error: null is not an object (evaluating 'point.hasOwnProperty'. Any ideas on a fix?

```
componentDidMount() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      error: null,
    });
  }
);
}

render() {

const lat = this.state.latitude;
const long = this.state.longitude;

let c = geolib.getDistance(
{latitude: lat, longitude: long}, //error occurs HERE
{latitude: 36.204824, longitude: 138.252924}
);

return (
    <Text>Distance: {c} kms</Text>
);
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this Denise?

Comment: your codes worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the following is async, which means it gives out results AFTER everything else is already loaded:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      error: null,
    });
  }
);
```

On first render, this.state.latitude will be null:

```
const lat = this.state.latitude;
const long = this.state.longitude;
```

Try adding this at the beginning of the render() method:

```
if (this.state.latitude == null) return null;
```

This will prevent the 1st render. The 2nd time it renders, this.state.latitude will be ready.